# Subtitles do not appear immediately after I have stopped them and enabled them again

Tags: video, vlc-media-player, subtitles, media-player, multimedia

I am using VLC media player to watch movies, and sometimes I enable subtitles with the <kbd>V</kbd> hotkey. And they work fine.

But if I accidentally press the <kbd>V</kbd> key again, and then one time more, the same line of the subtitles never appears again unless I rewind the video a bit backwards.

Is it possible to change this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, unfortunately. With "soft subs", which you certainly are using (from your described behavior), it is not possible to change this behavior, because the subtitle info consists only of text, start timestamp, and sometimes display duration. So if you're past the start timestamp, the subtitle "event" isn't seen and doesn't happen.

There might be other players that support the behavior you're looking for (as implementing it is conceivably possible), I do not know. But VLC's subtitle parser, from all my experience, doesn't support seeking backwards to look for the most recent subtitle from any given point.

*Note: OP points out in comments below that SMPlayer has this capability, so that is a potential alternate player.*

---

With "closed subs" (or "prerendered subs"), you'd see the behavior you want anyways, because these are just another video layer that can be hidden and displayed on top of the main video at will.

With "hard subs", you wouldn't be able to turn them off at all, really, since they are part of the actual video itself.

---

If for some reason you really *have* to have this behavior in a player that doesn't support this, you could try to find a tool that will render soft subs to a closed sub (prerendered) format. Then you should be able to use that, although you would lose some features like the ability to change subtitle fonts, colors, etc. on the fly.

---

That said; one alternate approach to solving your problem of accidentally pressing the key could be to change the keyboard shortcut to something like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> (or whatever, check that it doesn't conflict with anything else first) that is harder to accidentally press. Or disable the shortcut altogether if you never use it.

You can do this in VLC if you go to Tools → Preferences → Hotkeys.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'll try SMPlayer then, it has the behavior I need)

Comment: @DemianWolf I'll file that away too, I never used smplayer much with subs. Thanks for adding that, good to know.